# Class $C^1$ function?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Is this function class $C^1$ at $(0,0)$
?
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \frac{2x^2y+y^3}{x^2+y^2} &(x,y)\neq0 \\ \\
 0& (x,y)=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$
I thought like this, first i took partial derivative with respect to x and y:
$$\frac{\partial  f}{\partial x}=2y \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{2x^2+3y^2}{2y}$$and beacause
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{2x^2+3y^2}{2y}$ is not defined at zero i made conclusion that this function is not class $C^1$

Is that type of reasoning correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

We need to show that the funtion has continuous partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ with

$$f_x=\frac{2 x y^3}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} \quad f_y = \frac{2 x^4 + x^2 y^2 + y^4}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$$

and we can easily check that they are not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Refer also to

- [Partial derivatives must exist and be continuous on all defined points of $f$ for $f$ to be differentiable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/673160/505767)